# Ubuntu 20.04 : failure extract

Tags: disk, disk-usage, reboot, rar, free

System  inflates hard drive when it try failure extract some rar files. system cannot be reboot because there is no free space

Comment: I also tried to use ```Extract here``` option from default GUI menu on ubuntu 20.04 and it kept failing until I had no space on my hard drive. I finally used ```unrar``` package.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem; The issue seems to be happening with the package `unrar-free`. Installing `unrar-nonfree` (`sudo apt install unrar`) fixed the problem for me.
Note that this issue will (probably) be fixed in the next versions of `unrar-free`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when extracting a 2.2 GB .rar file. I used a live Ubuntu USB stick, selected "other locations" in the file manager, identified the .rar file that had grown to astonishing 450 GB but then couldn't delete it because the trash was not big enough...
The solution (took me at least one hour since I'm a total noob) was to:

- drag the file from the dolphin file manager directly onto the command line to get the path.
- type: "sudo rm" in front of that path and file name (only works with sudo)

The path was difficult for me to figure out because it was not the primary "HD" since I was coming from the USB stick.
I used on online extractor, extract.me to offload the risk of this going into insanity overdrive again.