# Why does it display "Filesystem root" almost full when I have almost 35GB worth of free space?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem, disk-usage, rar

I tried unzipping a 37MB RAR file, but system says root is full.
I used `sudo baobab /` to check, and it shows that / takes up 14.1GB. It acknowledges the fact that the free space exists, but it still shows root as full.
I ran `sudo du -h` in root and it shows 19GB.
I ran `sudo df -i` and it shows:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda5      3244032 321772 2922260   10% /
```

I ran `sudo df -h --total` and it shows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           394M  1.5M  393M   1% /run
/dev/sda5        49G   14G   33G  29% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      221M  221M     0 100% /snap/code/63
/dev/loop1      208M  208M     0 100% /snap/code/65
/dev/loop3       99M   99M     0 100% /snap/core/11081
/dev/loop2      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/10958
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop6      218M  218M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop7      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop8       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop9       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop11      52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop10      52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/498
/dev/loop12      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11588
/dev/loop13      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11841
/dev/sda1       511M  4.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           394M   60K  394M   1% /run/user/1000
total            58G   15G   40G  27% -
```

I used xdiskusage in two different ways:
`sudo xdiskusage /` , which showed 13.11GB, and
`sudo xdiskusage` and then chose from the graphical interface the disk / is mounted on, which showed 48.6GB, from which 32.94 is (free), 2.49 is (inodes) and the rest is the actual root.

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xee2b9e47

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576  512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 104857599 103804930 49.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 104855551 103802880 49.5G 83 Linux
```

The system is running on VMBox. It was initially allocated at 25GB but I expanded the partition into 50 using GParted. The problem started before I messed with the partitioning. I have rebooted the system, in case open but not deleted files are there. No large log files are present (only 349MB).

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `df -i`? This will show the `inode` usage. If you have a lot of little files filling the file system, then it doesn't matter how much empty space you might have, the file system itself will be unable to address new files beyond a certain limit.

Comment: Did you notice any small in-ram, leftover mounted /tmp, possibly created from a time when the filesystem did fill up?   That could trigger the problem too.

Comment: @matigo Done. Do you need all of it?

Comment: @ubfan1 Do you mean the number of files that are in there? There's just 15 of them.

Comment: `tmpfs           394M  1.4M  393M   1% /run`
`tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm`
`tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock`
`tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup`
`tmpfs           394M   52K  394M   1% /run/user/1000`
These are all the tmpfs that df shows. I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: The type of filesystem created is "overflow", not tmpfs when /tmp gets some in-ram space.   See https://askubuntu.com/questions/199565/not-enough-space-on-tmp

Comment: Thank you. No such line exists in the df -h results.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output of a sample run of the command that displays the "filesystem full" message?

Comment: I am simply trying to unzip a folder containing .csv files that my professor sent me.

Comment: OK. Then please paste the output of `unzip -l _the_zip_file_`. And also "test" the file using `unzip -t _the_zip_file_`

Comment: I used unrar, and it extracted the files with no issue. The test also comes out "All OK". Why would that be giving me an error message about filesystem root having 0 bytes of space, though?

Comment: Your problem may be related to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253156

Comment: My system seems to be working fine now, so that seems to be a similar problem, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I had a root partition report full on Mom's computer (Kubuntu 16.04).  The solution was to run:  sudo apt autoremove
In that case the update program never cleaned out the old files.  Now running 20.04, it runs fine.

Comment: I've done that, there was no difference.